# Improve tab-bar

Tags: tabs, tab-bar

What can I do to improve the design of the tab component?
(The one in the middle of the screen with "Overview", "Dependencies" and so on.

[image]

Comment: You should work on your information architecture. Card sorting or affinity mapping would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's any number of possible ways you could improve it, and ultimately depends one what you want the final product to look and behave like.

But how about some of these:

1. Centre the text for the tab

   - This is particularly noticeable with the multi-line tabs
2. A border between the tabs to help distinguish them apart from one another
3. A slightly darker background colour for the selected one

   - This may not be needed as you have the thick underline, but sometimes it's also good to show the tab as if it were "pressed in" (like a button)
4. Consistent use of an icon (or no icon)

   - What is the significance of the arrows icon for the "Dependencies" tab?
5. Equal tab width

   - This may not always be possible (or necessary), but can highlight that each of the tabs are equally important.
   - An alternative to this is to widen all of the tabs and have them over a couple of lines, some people don't like this (or take it too far with 3+ rows of buttons)
   - You could instead put related items under one Dropdown menu ([Bootstrap example](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/#supported-content))